# Efficiently Store And Query Unique Integers and Integer Ranges

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures, database-design, data-science

Let's say we have a set of integers from 0 to positive K (can go to positive infinity) all painted white. We decide to randomly paint a random amount those integers Red. When painting integers Red, we can either paint values one by one, we can select a range of values and paint them all at once, or any combination of both. All remaining untouched values are automatically painted blue.

The end goal is to quickly figure out what integers are painted blue.

All integers can be re-painted red by others. Every time an integer is painted red, the unique name of the person who chose to paint it gets appended to the integer so others will know who else has painted it red.

The question is, what kind of database structure should I instead model that would allow me to quickly figure out what values are blue without storing every single red value? Is there any other way? Are there examples of database structures and query algorithm combinations I could look at and learn from?

Comment: Your question still has an inconsistency.  "we have a set of integers from 0 to positive K all painted white" & "All remaining untouched values are automatically painted blue" So, why don't all the integers from 0 to positive k start out blue?

Comment: "Every time an integer is painted red, the unique name of the person who chose to paint it gets appended to the integer so others will know who else has painted it red."  A new requirement, this painter's name has to be stored in a separate red table.  The blue table row still consists of a starting integer and an ending integer.  Whether or not the ending integer is inclusive or exclusive is up to you.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc to help explain/visualize this better I wrote they all start out white. They do all start blue

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc a user on my original question stated I needed to resubmit this again after adding the "All integers can be re-painted red by others. " portion. I need to add a portion specifying that K goes to positive infinity

Comment: What's more important than blue going from zero to positive infinity is the set of red numbers.  How many numbers are in the set of red numbers?  What is the range of the set of red numbers?  If the answer is positive infinity, then you can't store this information in a finite database.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc red and blue integers can range from 0 to 18446744073709551615, the largest 64 bit number possible

Comment: Great.  Like I asked before, how many numbers are in the red set.  I need an approximate count, not just a limit.

Comment: Let me help you.  At 10 ^ 6 red values, you've hit the limit of free databases.  At 10 ^ 8, you're talking about the limit of single machine paid databases.  At 10 ^ 10 and up, be prepared to spend millions or even billions of dollars on hardware and software.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc This is why I asked this question. I do not want to store hundreds of millions of integers. Red and blue can range from 0 to positive infinity. There is no limit to how many can be painted. For testing purposes, if you'd like, say we start with a million unstored blue integers, they can be painted red in any order.

Comment: "Every time an integer is painted red, the unique name of the person who chose to paint it gets appended to the integer so others will know who else has painted it red." Explain to me how you accomplish this without storing every single red integer multiple times (once for each name)?  Unless you have a practical application for this problem, I'm done.  You cannot ignore reality.

Answer (score 0):

According to your problem description, you have two tables.  A red table and a blue table.

Let's start with the red table.

```
Red
---
Red ID
Integer
User ID
```

The Red ID is an auto-incrementing integer primary clustering key value.  It's also called a blind key.  It has no other meaning than to provide a primary key for this table.

So, for an integer range, there will be multiple rows in the table.  If you wish, you can create unique indexes on (Integer, User ID) so you can easily find who painted a particular integer red and (User ID, Integer) so you can easily find what integers a particular user painted red.

The Blue table row is simply a starting integer and an ending integer.

```
Blue
----
Blue ID
Starting integer
Ending Integer
```

The Blue ID is an auto-incrementing integer primary clustering key value.  It's also called a blind key.  It has no other meaning than to provide a primary key for this table.

The rows of this table will not be stored in ascending integer order.  That's okay.  Other indexes will maintain the order of the integers.

You create a unique index on Starting integer and a unique index on Ending integer.

To find a particular integer in the blue table, the SELECT WHERE clause would look like this:

```
WHERE integer >= Starting integer AND integer <= Ending integer.
```

The blue table starts with one row.  For this example, let's make K 100.

```
Blue ID | Starting Integer | Ending Integer
-------------------------------------------
      1                  0              100
```

Okay.  Someone comes along and paints 24 red.  The red table is updated with the information.  The blue table is modified to look like this.

```
Blue ID | Starting Integer | Ending Integer
-------------------------------------------
      1                  0               23
      2                 25              100
```

So what happened is the number 24 was in between 0 and 100.  So that row was updated with a new ending integer.  Then a new row was added to cover the remaining numbers.

So far, the blue table is in numerical order.  That won't last.

Someone comes along and paints 12 red.  The blue table is modified to look like this.

```
Blue ID | Starting Integer | Ending Integer
-------------------------------------------
      1                  0               11
      2                 25              100
      3                 13               23
```

Each time a number is painted red, a new row in the blue table is created.  This works well if less than half the numbers between 0 and K are painted red.  If more than half the numbers between 0 and K are painted red.  It would make more sense to start out creating K rows of a single integer and deleting each row when it's painted red.

You didn't specify this limit, so I leave this decision up to you.

Finally, this process will be 1,000 times faster (at least) if the blue table is an in-memory table.  If K is so large that the table can't be kept in memory, then this will be a slow process.

Comment: This is heading in the right direction though since k can go to infinity, the blue table would be slow to query like you said.

Comment: The algorithm and database structure are meant to only allow reds to be painted once so that everyone can tell what is still left to paint. The reds keep track of who painted them red so they can tell how many users chose them, everyone is allowed to paint whatever integer they want and everyone can see who painted any integer.

Comment: @firebaser: I'm not sure I understand your comment.  An integer is either in the red table or the blue table.  If it's in the red table, you need a row for each and every user id that painted it red.  So, theoretically, the red table can contain K times the number of users rows.  if K goes to infinity, then you can theoretically have an infinite number of rows in the blue table.  You can't store infinite rows in a database.